# terminate mips assembly programm mit jr $ra

Tags: assembly, mips

Normally I would terminate my programm with

```
li        $v0, 10
syscall
```

Now I've seen many code examples where they terminate the programm by jumping back to the $ra register.

```
jr        $ra
```

Why is this possible to terminate the program like this? Does it depend on the compiling program?

Recent main I've looked in:

main:

```
    addi    $sp, $sp, -4        # save return adress
    sw  $ra, 0($sp)

    lw  $a0, x              #get some arguments for a function called exp
    lw  $a1, n              #get more args

    jal exp                 #call the function

    move    $s1, $v0

    move    $a0, $s1

    li  $v0, 1               #print return value
    syscall
    lw  $ra, 0($sp)          #here we load the ra for the jr
    addi    $sp, $sp, 4
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: Depends on your environment. Typically if you have `main` that means you can return from it.

Comment: This works if the process doesn't start with `main()` but instead with some `_start()` which loads libraries, sets up the environment, calls `main()` and, crucially, terminates the process gracefully when `main()` returns.

Comment: Okay lets say I'm in my main function and I use a jal to another function. In that function at the end I use jr $ra to return back to MY main. How does QtSPIM for example knows that I want to go to MY main and not the main of QtSPIM? The return adress is the same and I didnt stored and loaded it on the stack pointer. For declaration after .text I set .globl main as I'm doing it in university and then start coding my main in main: [CODE]

Comment: @Richie If you are in function `a()` and you have not saved `$ra` before calling `b()`, then returning from `a()` after `b()` has returned will lead to an infinite loop (unless stack adjustments/register restoration in `a()` leads to a fault).

Comment: There is no magic in QtSPIM, or in real CPUs in general.  `jr $ra` means jump to the address in that register, nothing more, nothing less.  A function that wants to use `jal` itself has to save/restore `$ra`, or else it will lose its return address.  (If you don't do this, then the pointer in `$ra` will be to the instruction after the last `jal` like EOF said, often creating an infinite loop of the few instructions at the end of your function.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes Is there aswell a mips tags like in your profile for x86 with all documentation and so one?

Comment: Yeah, mouseover the MIPS tag in your question and click info.  Unfortunately the MIPS tag wiki is nowhere near as big as x86; I only have the time/energy/interest to really maintain the x86 tag wiki.  I do edit others sometimes.

Comment: In `main`, doing `li $v0,10`, `syscall` is like (in C) doing `exit(0)`. Doing `jr $ra` is like: `int main(void) { return 0; }`. Or, more correctly, since most `mips` simulators don't honor the return codes: `exit()` and `void main(void) { return; }` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`jr  $ra` is the equivalent of `ret` on x86 or `bx lr` on ARM, it's often the case where we're not writing an entire program but just a single function or routine, that returns to a main program. This is how you tell the CPU that you wish to return to the instruction after the `jal` or `jalr` that got you here. (Well, since it's MIPS, it would be the instruction 2 down from the call point but I digress.)